# what is the efficient way of read mysqlbin log to keep informed about every event in sqldb?

Tags: mysql, java, mysqlbinlog

I want to keep updated about tranformation happening in mysql db and based on each event i want to do some processing and send data to some rest api on other server.

My plan is :

Read mysqlbinlog using [mysqlbinlog connector](https://github.com/shyiko/mysql-binlog-connector-java) in java and do processing and send updates.

I wanted to know is it efficient and how to control the huge rate of updates in mysqldb. As reading from mysqlbinlogs is single threaded.

Comment: Reading the binlog requires some code, but it is probably the most efficient way.

Comment: @RickJames..any known efficient java plugins which allow execution of custom code for every event?

Comment: Maybe a message queue service in your infrastructure to ensure some events can trigger multiple listeners.